# Finding edges of 2d point cloud and painting area inside it

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, math

I am currently building a car simulator environment in Carla, and im trying to create a birds eye view of the surrounding, using semantic camera segmentation and lidar.

Here you can find images to more easily explain what i want:
[image: T junction]
[image: Another T junction]
[image: Curved road]
[image: Traffic]

So green colors are dots that represent the road, while red dots are road lines. Blue dots are cars and you can notice empty space between them, since those are not positions that lidar picked up.

My question is, what would be the best way to connect these dots, or find edges and "paint" the area inside, better say convert all [0,0,0] pixels to same pixel value as green points for the area inside, thus painting the whole road for instance.

Id also like to do the same with red values, which are lanes, kinda intensifying them and connecting them to make better visible lines.

I have data as a list of relative coordinates to the center, or simply as an image matrix.
This is snippet of code that transforms lidar data to this image.

```
LIDAR_RANGE = 100
lidar_data  = #This is data from lidar in shape of 
              #[N_points,4] , x,y,z value with semantic value
              # like 1 for car, 2 for road, 3 for pedestrian
disp_size = [400,500]
lidar_range = float(LIDAR_RANGE) * 2.0
points = lidar_data
points[:,:2] *= min(disp_size) / lidar_range
points[:,:2] += (0.5 * disp_size[0], 0.5 * disp_size[1])
points[:,:2] = np.fabs(points[:,:2])
points = points.astype("int32")

lidar_img_size = (disp_size[0],disp_size[1],3)
lidar_img = np.zeros((lidar_img_size),dtype=np.int8)
for point in points:#need to transform this to numpy 
    if point[3] == 4:
        lidar_img[point[0]][point[1]] = [220,20,60]
    elif point[3] == 6:
        lidar_img[point[0]][point[1]] = [157,234,50]
    elif point[3] == 7:
        lidar_img[point[0]][point[1]] = [128,64,128]
    elif point[3] == 10:
        lidar_img[point[0]][point[1]] = [0,0,142]
    elif point[3] == 18:
        lidar_img[point[0]][point[1]] = [250,170,30]
    else:
        lidar_img[point[0]][point[1]] = [0,0,0]
lidar_img = np.flip(lidar_img, axis = 0)
cv2.imshow("3", lidar_img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
return lidar_img
```

Comment: What about using the convex hull to get bounds?

Comment: @fmw42 i think convex hull would mess up any place where the road turns or i have intersection, right? It would connect points outside aswell.

Comment: It will enclose all points with a convex polygon that touches some of the points

Comment: Have a look at techniques like delauny triangulation, tessellation, medial axis, etc. In general, no algorithm can know whether a set of points build a convex or a concave contour, unless you have additional information or assumptions.

Comment: I suppose maybe concave hull would be better? I managed to research just a litttle bit @fmw42.